# Silence exception in django template tag

Tags: django, exception, django-templates

I am writing a very simple template tag, which returns the verbose name of a application:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_name(app_name):
    return apps.get_app_config(app_name).verbose_name
```

According to the documentation I should return default values and not throw exceptions if possible. Should I handle the exception and return None or throw it if the question doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

You should always `try` `catch` possible exceptions (i.e handle them) in python and of course in Django! Its a good practice.

So, what I would do is this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_verbose_name(app_name):
    try:
        verbose_name = apps.get_app_config(app_name).verbose_name
    except LookupError:
        return 'No app for {}'.format(app_name)
    else:
        return verbose_name
```